# can't use firebase firestorage in flutter foreground_task handler class

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, foreground-service

i have a flutter app that is supposed to run even when i close it. For that i used the plugin flutter_foreground_task and in myclass, that extends TaskHandler, I need to use `FirebaseFirestore.instance.get` method, but in my case i got the exception:

> No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()

I found that the exception comes because the `TaskHandler` starts to run before the main method, where the Firebase gets initialized.

This is MyTaskHandler class code :

```
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'package:flutter_foreground_task/flutter_foreground_task.dart';
import 'MyFireStorage.dart';
import 'sockets/client.dart';


class MyTaskHandler extends TaskHandler {
  SendPort? _sendPort;
  int _eventCount = 0;
  late Client client;
  
  String get_ip(){
    String m = ''; 
    MyFireStorage().getServerIpAdress().then((value) {
      m = value;
    });
    return m;
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onStart(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) async {
    _sendPort = sendPort;
    client = Client(
        hostname: get_ip(), 
        port: 4040,
        onData: (data) => null,
        onError: (data) => print(data),
      );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onEvent(DateTime timestamp, SendPort? sendPort) async {
    FlutterForegroundTask.updateService(
      notificationTitle: 'MyTaskHandler',
      notificationText: 'eventCount: $_eventCount',
    );

    // Send data to the main isolate.
    sendPort?.send(_eventCount);

    _eventCount--;

    client.write('$_eventCount');

  }

}
```

i tried to make a static variable in MyFireStorage and use its value in MyTaskHandler but i got the same exception
i also tried to save the value in the app cache data using shared_preferences but it didn't work